# Show/Hide inline Form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have an inline form on my webpage that is hidden by css when the page is loaded. I also have a button to display the form. However, I want that same button to hide the form if it's clicked again. But I can't seem to get it working, instead when I click the inline form button the form disappears even though I never assigned a function to it.

Here's my HTML

```
<button id="signup" onclick="showForm('inline')">SignUp!</button>

        <!-- hidden inline form -->
        <div id="inline">
        <h2>Register! It's free!</h2>
        <form id="register" action="#" method="post" name="register">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input id="email" class="txt" type="email" name="email" />

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input id="password" class="passtxt" type="password" name="password" />

        <label for="password">Repeat Password:</label>
            <input id="password" class="passtxt" type="password" name="password" />

        <button id="registerbtn">Register</button>
        </form> 
        </div>
```

Here's my JS:

```
function showForm(form) {

    var e = document.getElementById(form);

    if (e.style.display = 'none') 
        e.style.display = 'inline';
    else
    e.style.display = 'none';

}
```

When I click the signup button, the form shows. However if I click it again nothing happens. But if i click the register button in the form, it disappears. Why? and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:** I chose DaveHogan's as the best answer as it was what I was looking for. But I have switched over to using JQuery instead, and if you're reading this. You should switch too.

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery? Not only will your code be shorter and easier to understand, it will also work on all browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear you're not checking the equality correctly (use double equals).

```
if (e.style.display == 'none')
```

Comment: ooooh. Didn't even cross my mind to try that..Thanks. It works! But the form still disappears if I hit the registerbtn

Comment: When you click the button within the form tag it's posting the data. The webpage essentially reloads losing the state of the previous page.

Answer (score 3):

If you would use jQuery, you could use toggle :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Se5bm/

```
<div id="foo">omg </div>
<button id="bar">toggle me</button>​

$('#bar').bind('click' , function() {
    $('#foo').toggle();
});
​
```

Comment: Yes I suppose I should start using jQuery instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you must to remember that "=" is not the same that "==",  = is to assign and == is for questions, something like this... A = B, in this case you are assign that A is equal to B, if you write A == B you are asking if A is equal to B